# Unicode/UTF-8 problems in ssh session with Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: server, ssh, unicode, utf-8

I have a fresh Ubuntu Server 16.04 installation, and I am now testing how it handles unicode characters:

- I have a file name with a unicode character in it: `testā.txt`. If I pick up it with a tab, ie `$ rm tes[tab]`, then a correct file name is picked up to the command.
- If I do `$ ls`, I see `test??.txt` in the file list
- If I add unicode characters to the file contents with `$ echo āāā > test.txt`, and then do `$ cat test.txt`, I get correct output.
- However, if I open the file in nano editor, the contents look like this: `^ ^ ^`.
- Hex dump `$ xxd test.txt` shows that the unicode characters are stored in the file correctly: `c481 c481 c481 0a`

The terminal program I am using (Guake) never had any problems with unicode characters. In typical local terminal session there are none of the problems described above.

Calling `env | sort | grep -E '^(LANG(UAGE)?|LC_\w*)='` gives

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_ADDRESS=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_NAME=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=lv_LV.UTF-8
LC_TIME=lv_LV.UTF-8
```

Is this something that can be fixed with the server locale settings?
Or there is some parameter I should use when initiating the ssh session?

Comment: The behavior seems to indicate that (1) your terminal emulator understands UTF-8, and (2) the locale of the session is not UTF-8. Please do `env | sort | grep -E '^(LANG(UAGE)?|LC_\w*)='` to show locale-related environment variables; edit the question to include the results. You may then have to `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` and/or update your login scripts.

Comment: Added the output. Is there any information that explains the missing characters behavior?